# Where is the option to add a Xamarin UI automation test project in Visual Studio? Is it removed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, xamarin.uitest

I can't see the option to add a UI automation test project in Visual studio anymore. Did they remove it?

[image]

tried to add it but it's not there anymore

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing as well when starting a new project. VS 2019 for mac still has that template but VS for mac 2022 does not. However, when you use that template it would make a project using .NET framework. Xamarin.UITest has just recently made itself compatible with .NET 6 if you use version 4 and higher. I would recommend version 4.1.0 and higher since out-of-the-box version 4 was very broken. When I made my new .NET 6 project using Xamarin.UITest I just used the basic Nunit template you have there.